# Android Studio Error Message at runtime

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Would you please explain about the error message and solution?

I was working on android studio , My task was very easy , just adding 2 numbers using a library . Last time when it run successfully , I didn't add the jar file 
. But After adding the jar file , the project run no longer . When I press run , it shows the error message and stop working .

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 5.158 secs
>   Information:3 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

[Full error message log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/15910539/)

[My Full Java and XML code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15910529/)

[Library](http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/)

[project : build.gradle code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/15910769/)

Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blogspot.virtualn0t3b00k.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/flanagan.jar')
}
```

Comment: add build.gradle file code

Comment: @USKMobility https://paste.ubuntu.com/15910769/

Comment: @noob there are two build.gradle files. Open app's build.gradle. please see my answer

Comment: remove your unused jar files and libraries.

Comment: Please don't use paste sites or Google Drive for your code and errors.

Comment: @cricket_007
For codes : The code ( java+xml+gradle) would be very long to paste , but 
after all of this , do you suggest me to paste at post? I will follow later
For project : Finding no other alternatives I am posting the full project link. If there is any problem with google drive , suggest me what I should use ? ( Dropbox , others )

Comment: You are getting a compile error. The Java code isn't necessary. If you read how to make a [mcve], then the **minimal** but **complete** parts are important. Basically, if you know where the exactly the error is in the code, then only show that section. In this case, you only need the Gradle output and mention any libraries you are using. I have already provided my answer below which explains that you are unable to use the library that you have downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

So after downloading your code, the **real** error is below...

The problem is that Android can't run Java 8 compiled code, which is what [the library uses](http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/) if you read

> The current version of Java Platform 8 used in compiling the classes in flanagan.jar is jdk1.8.0.

Also, the JAR file includes some AWT and Swing packages that aren't included in the Android SDK, so the code wouldn't compile completely, anyway.

And that would explain why you say

> After adding the jar file , the project run no longer

The error

```
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
        ... 12 more

1 error; aborting
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply.

So after all of this you have seen , Please suggest me :
1) Is it "MANDATORY" to remove flanagan.jar from my project and I have to find other alternatives for complex number calculation ? (you can suggest me any alternatives)
2) Is there any way to reuse flanagan.jar by somehow?

Comment: 2) You might be able to re-compile the code with Java 7 if you download the sources, but 1) If you only care about the complex numbers, then the Apache commons-math library has a `Complex` class.

Answer (score 0):

Enable multidex support in build.gradle configuration.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blogspot.virtualn0t3b00k.myapplication"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'

}
```

If also failed then add following code in your application class

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
    {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

Probably your problem will be solved.

Comment: I will edit project's build.gradle or app's build.gradle or both?

Comment: app's build.gradle

Comment: step 1 :
error :  https://paste.ubuntu.com/15910866

step 2:
error :   MultiDex.install(this);   >>>> MuliDex not found

step 3: 
error : https://paste.ubuntu.com/15911047/

Comment: If you are interested here is everything : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3o3vhrnqE-MZGtwaG1MSUVKY2s/view

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your build.gradle after buildTypes and before dependencies and yes don't forget to remove unused jar files and compile files(libraries).

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
}
```

Clean your project once after doing all.

Comment: not working , you can see the whole file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3o3vhrnqE-MZGtwaG1MSUVKY2s/view

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this in build.gradle file

```
defaultConfig {        
// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Please remove the line

```
compile files('libs/flanagan.jar')
```

from app's build.gradle file because

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

line includes the library flanagan.jar which is in libs folder.So adding

```
compile files('libs/flanagan.jar') is duplicating and giving the error
```

Comment: check your build.gradle file. There will be two build.gradle files. try this in app's build.gradle

Comment: Link is now on the post

Comment: @noob did you add `multiDexEnabled true` in app's build.gradle file?

Comment: @noob remove in project and add in app and let me know if the problem is fixed

Comment: Dashari
I have tried those methods, not working for me
if you are interested please see the full file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3o3vhrnqE-MZGtwaG1MSUVKY2s/view?usp=sharing